# Is there any way to get \r (Carriage Return) from XML file unconverted?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

The XML specification states that this has to be the behaviour for handling any "external parsed entity". But this applies to CDATA sections inside of an element as well? Why?
Is there any way to get \r unconverted by adding 1/2 conditions in parser code, instead of changing `\r` to `&#13;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the case. Why? It is to simplify the life of the applications that will process the output from the XML file - they simply do not need to worry in which format the newlines are, increasing application compatibility (consider compatibility of simple text editors between Linux and Windows - they almost always display the files incorrectly, in Windows most often as a single line).

Of course, if you, for any reason, require having \r unconverted, it is simple to take any existing XML parser implementation and modify it. In tinyxml, you need to modify the TiXmlBase::ReadText() function, or you can grab an older version of it, as it used to leave whitespace intact.

On the other hand, from the design point of view, it would be much cleaner to just run parser output through character replacement function and replace all the "\n" to "\r\n".

Of course the best would be to just use the output as is, right now I can't imagine any scenario where this would be needed.

Comment: There can be a scenario, when some confidential data in XML file with \r is encoded into barcode and when you try to read the data back, all you find is data with \n
Data must not be changed for it is being encoded for security reasons.

Comment: Ahaa - in that case, it is quite common to encode the data as BASE64 and *then* putting it in XML. XML doesn't preserve whitespace (by design) and all by itself is not suitable for storing binary data.

Answer (score 1):

CDATA is not named character data for nothing. The only elegant way to deal with you situation is to encode is as Base64.

Base64 encodes all 255 possible characters in 64 printable characters. 
To get 255 possibilities in 64 options makes the text a bit bigger, but that will be your only option except for changing your XML layout to something like

```
<TEXT>
  <CHAR>13</CHAR>
  <CHAR>255</CHAR>
</TEXT>
```

But in my opinion that's even worse then the `&#13;` you now get.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-cdata/
Visit this site for more information about dealing with binary data in your XML.

Hope it helps you.